# Delivering a file over ssl and non ssl (http and https) in IIS

Tags: iis, ssl

To avoid mixed content warnings I would like to have a file that can be delivered under both protocols (http/https).  Ie.

http://www.site.com/file.js
and
https://www.site.com/file.js

I've had a look at google analytics injection code and they use a diferent domain, i.e:
http://www.google.com and https://ssl.google.com.

Now I would like something a little 'cleaner'?  I really don't want to have 2 websites to mantain.  Does anyone know if this is possible in IIS?

Thanks

Guido

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have to be a different domain, it will typically use the domain just a different port. See "[How to Setup an HTTPS Service in IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324069)."

**EDIT**
I see you you are talking about mixing SSL and non SSL, so if my answer above doesn't help. It seems that using relative URLs are the answer. Take a look at [Http-https transitions and relative URLs](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200710/httphttps_transitions_and_relative_urls.html).

Comment: Nope, setting up https is not the question, also using relative paths to avoid mixed content warnings is also not the question.  I need to deliver 1 file via both ssl and non ssl.  I.e: http://www.site.com/file.js and https://www.site.com/file.js (should both work).  I dont think IIS lets you do this, so I think I will need 2 'web sites' or at least virtual directories to deliver this file.

Comment: (My http and https were removed by editor, but just look at original post)